# Cohomology of Hypersurface complement

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Suppose $Y$ is a smooth hypersurface in projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$, $X = \mathbb{P}^n - Y$ is the hypersurface complement. Is there a general method to compute cohomology of $X$? In particular, for small n, is there any examples or references?

Comment: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~aleykin3/Dmodules/_de__Rham.html

Comment: I think the reference deal with hypersurface complement of affine variety.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is **very** computable, using several methods. I assume you are over $\mathbb{C}$ and
that by cohomology
you mean singular cohomology, but other choices are also just as straight forward.
Let $P=\mathbb{P}^n$.
Then by the Gysin sequence
$$ \ldots H^i(P)\to H^i(X)\to H^{i-1}(Y)\to H^{i+1}(P)\ldots $$
you can basically reduce it to the computation of $H^i(P)$, which is standard, and
$H^i(Y)$.
There are a number of explicit formulas for the latter. See, for example,
[http://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/book-chap17.pdf](http://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Edvb/preprints/book-chap17.pdf)

**Notes**: The connecting map $H^{i-1}(Y)\to H^{i+1}(P)$ is the Gysin map, which is Poincaré dual
to the restriction $H^{2n-i-1}(P)\to H^{2n-i-1}(Y)$. Alternately, choose a tubular neighbourhood
$Y\subset T\subset P$ and
identify
$$H^{i-1}(Y)= H^{i-1}(T) = H^{i+1}(T,\partial T)=H^{i+1}(P,X)$$
by excision and the Thom isomorphism. Then this is the usual connecting map, and the
sequence is long exact sequence for the pair $(P,X)$. There other ways to understand
this as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to determine the connecting homomorphism please? Thanks!

Comment: OK, I added something.

Comment: The link isn't working for me.

Comment: Sorry but he original link was disabled since the book has been published and I didn't want to get sued. However, I've linked the relevant pages.

Comment: Does this work for homotopy as well?

Answer (score 3):

Griffiths (On the periods of certain rational integrals. I, II. Ann. of Math. 90 (1969), 460-495 & 90 (1969), 496–541.) gave a procedure to calculate the Hodge numbers of Y. Let $S=\mathbf{C}[x_0,\dots,x_n]$, let $f$ be an equation for $Y$ and $d$ be its degree. Let $J_f$ be the jacobian ideal of $f$, i.e., the ideal generated by the partial derivatives of $f$. Then
$$ h^{i,n-1-i}(Y)=\delta_{i,n-1-i}+\dim (S/J_f)_{id-n-1}.$$
The other Hodge numbers can be obtained from by hyperplane theorems: i.e., if $p+q\neq n-1$ then $h^{p,q}(Y)=1$ if and only if $0\leq p=q\leq n-1$ holds. All other Hodge numbers are zero.

Here, $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta, $S$ has a natural grading, $J_f$ is generated by homogeneous elements and therefore $S/J_f$ is a graded ring. $(S/J_f)_k$ means all elements of degree $k$.

The above formula can be generalized, see e.g., Steenbrink (Intersection form for quasi-homogeneous singularities. Compositio Math. 34 (1977), 211–223) for weighted projective spaces of Dimca (Betti numbers of hypersurfaces and defects of linear systems.
Duke Math. J. 60 (1990), 285–298) for hypersurfaces with isolated weighted homogeneous singularities.